# Prevent edge clipping with Graphviz dot

Tags: dot

Is there a way to prevent edge clipping in Graphviz dot so that an edge can start or end at the center of a node instead of at the node edge? What I would like to do is point *into* a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headclip & tailclip attributes are what you want. e.g. headclip=false.  https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#a:headclip

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work if the node contains an (HTML) table.